# ROS Public Facing Server

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I recently bought a security camera that once connected to your WiFi network lets you view the video from anywhere via their app, no changing router settings required. I'm wondering if it would be possible to set this up with a ROS robot?

I've been  asking around and it seems like one possible solution is to create some sort of intermediary server that the Robot would know to publish data to, and the app knows to pull data from. But I have no idea how I would set up a server like that or what its even called.

Any advise is greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267636/ros-public-facing-server/) by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 545 on 2017-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One way to do these things (the camera use-case) is to use something called *nat punching*.

But that isn't really convenient for something like ROS, which uses many (randomly chosen) TCP and UDP ports.

You could take a look at something like a P2P VPN such as [tinc](https://www.tinc-vpn.org) to create an overlay network. Besides the fact that its cross-platform, behaves like a virtual NIC (so no proxies, binary wrapping or other socket tricks), it's also safer as it encrypts the traffic between nodes - a nice thing when (vanilla) ROS1 does not do that for you.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0